# How to prevent .scroll() function execution when scrolling performed by dragging the bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which hide some headers while box is scrolling down and appearing headers when it scrolls up. It works fine, but if I scroll the page not by mouse-wheel or touchpad, and use mouse button on scrollbar - the event start to repeat, I mean if I will slowly scroll down by dragging, headers hides and shows hides, shows etc.

I want to know if there a way to stop event handler after it have been executed once while mouse button is pressed?

Thanks.

My code:

```
const throttleHidings = _.throttle(headerHidings, 400);

$(".data-table").scroll(throttleHidings);

function headerHidings() {
  const element = $(".hiding-part"),
                  t = "transparent";
  let scrollPosition = $(".data-table").scrollTop();


  if (scrollPosition - contentScrollPosition > 0) {
    scrollingDown = true;
    lastPos.bottom = scrollPosition;
    contentScrollPosition = scrollPosition;
  }

  if (scrollPosition - contentScrollPosition < 0) {
    scrollingDown = false;
    contentScrollPosition = scrollPosition;
    lastPos.top = scrollPosition; 
  }

  if (scrollingDown) {
    hiding(scrollPosition - lastPos.top);
  } else {
    showing(lastPos.bottom - scrollPosition);
  }  

  function hiding(pos) {
    if (pos > 100) {
      $table.height("calc(100% - 133px)");
      element.slideUp(150);
    }
  }

  function showing(pos) {
    if (pos > 50) {
      element.slideDown(150, () => $table.height("calc(100% - 340px)"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer executing your function, e.g., using `setTimeout`, to "throttle" handling of `scroll` events. Every time `scroll` happens, wait like 150 milliseconds. If it happens again sooner, `clearTimeout` and set it again.

**Update:** here's version of your code that seems to be working (although i removed throttling, so it probably should be added later). It does not really show or hide any element - just outputs info, so you can see what it would be doing in full-blown version.

```js
$(".data-table").scroll(headerHidings);

var contentScrollPosition = $(".data-table").scrollTop();
var lastPos = {
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0
};

var $info = $(".info");

function headerHidings() {
  const element = $(".hiding-part"),
    t = "transparent";
  let scrollPosition = $(".data-table").scrollTop();


  if (scrollPosition - contentScrollPosition > 0) {
    scrollingDown = true;
    lastPos.bottom = scrollPosition;
    contentScrollPosition = scrollPosition;
  }

  if (scrollPosition - contentScrollPosition < 0) {
    scrollingDown = false;
    contentScrollPosition = scrollPosition;
    lastPos.top = scrollPosition;
  }

  if (scrollingDown) {
    hiding(scrollPosition - lastPos.top);
  } else {
    showing(lastPos.bottom - scrollPosition);
  }

  function hiding(pos) {
    if (pos > 100) {
      //$table.height("calc(100% - 133px)");
      //element.slideUp(150);
      $info.text('hiding on: ' + pos);
    }
  }

  function showing(pos) {
    if (pos > 50) {
      //element.slideDown(150, () => $table.height("calc(100% - 340px)"));
      $info.text('showing on: ' + pos);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.data-table {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 150px;
  background: green;
}
.fake-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3000px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info">
    Nothing happened yet.
</div>

<div class="data-table">
  <div class="fake-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to use throttle function from underscore.js but it still didn't work(added code into question)

Comment: I added snippet version of your code. It seems to be working ok, at least in Chrome.